# Use SSH in gitg without starting ssh-agent

Tags: git, ssh, gitg

When I fetch from a remote repository via an SSH Url, I get the error `no auth sock variable`. After starting an ssh agent, the error disappears and it works again:

```sh
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
gitg
```

Is there a way to use ssh with gitg without having an ssh agent running?

Comment: Can we see your `~/.ssh/config`? The problem is probably there.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.ssh/config` file, only plain ol' defaults.